# Problems implementing progress bar into an onclick method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog, progress-bar

i'm currently facing problem trying to figure out how to implement a progress bar into my program in order to inform users of the progress while waiting for it to calculate the scheduling. This is the significant part of my coding.

```
    Button btnOp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOption1);
                btnOp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int year1 = datePicker.getYear();
                        int mnth1 = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
                        int dy1 = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                        int hr1 = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        int min1 = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

                        fDate1 = (pad(year1)) + ("-") + (pad(mnth1))
                             + ("-") + (pad(dy1));
                        fTime = (pad(hr1)) + (":") + (pad(min1));


                        ScheduleOp1();  
                            }
                    private Object pad(int b) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (b >= 10){
                            return String.valueOf(b);
                        }else{
                           return "0" + String.valueOf(b);
                        }


                    }
                   });  
protected void ScheduleOp1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Cursor cur = null;
            boolean mustCont = true;
            while (mustCont){
                db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " +view_Schedule1);
                db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " +view_Schedule1+ " " +
                        " AS SELECT " +sBusDepart+ "," +sBusArrival+ "," 
                        +sBusDepartT+ "," +sBusArrivalT+ " FROM" + " "
                        +fDepart+ " " + "INNER JOIN" + " " +sBusSchedule+ " " +
                        "ON " +sBusSchedule+ "." +sBusDate+ "=" +fDepart+ "." 
                        +fDate+ " " + "WHERE " +fDate+ "= '" +fDate1+"'"+" "+
                        "AND" + " " +sBusDepartT+ " " + "= strftime('%H:%M', '" +fTime+ "', '" +getVarMin()+"');");
                cur = fetchAllTodos();

                if (cur.getCount() == 0){

                    switch (min){
                    case 140 :
                        min = 141;
                        break;
                    case 141 :
                        min = 142;
                        break;
                    case 142 :
                        min = 143;
                        break;
                    case 143 :
                        min = 144;
                        break;
                    case 144 :
                        min = 145;
                        break;
                    case 145 :
                        min = 146;
                        break;
                    case 146 :
                        min = 147;
                        break;
                    case 147 :
                        min = 148;
                        break;
                    case 148 :
                        min = 149;
                        break;
                    case 149:
                        min = 150;
                        break;
                    case 150 :
                        min = 151;
                        break;
                    case 151 :
                        min = 152;
                        break;
                    case 152 :
                        min = 153;
                        break;
                    case 153 :
                        min = 154;
                        break;
                    case 154 :
                        min = 155;
                        break;
                    case 155 :
                        min = 156;
                        break;
                    case 156 :
                        min = 157;
                        break;
                    case 157 :
                        min = 158;
                        break;
                    case 158 :
                        min = 159;
                        break;
                    case 159 :
                        min = 160;
                        break;
                    case 160 :
                        min = 161;
                        break;
                    case 161 :
                        min = 162;
                        break;
                    case 162 :
                        min = 163;
                        break;
                    case 163 :
                        min = 164;
                        break;
                    case 164 :
                        min = 165;
                        break;
                    case 165 :
                        min = 166;
                        break;
                    case 166 :
                        min = 167;
                        break;
                    case 167 :
                        min = 168;
                        break;
                    case 168 :
                        min = 169;
                        break;
                    case 169 :
                        min = 170;
                        break;
                    case 170 :
                        min = 171;
                        break;
                    case 171 :
                        min = 172;
                        break;
                    case 172 :
                        min = 173;
                        break;
                    case 173 :
                        min = 174;
                        break;
                    case 174 :
                        min = 175;
                        break;
                    case 175 :
                        min = 176;
                        break;
                    case 176 :
                        min = 177;
                        break;
                    case 177 :
                        min = 178;
                        break;
                    case 178 :
                        min = 179;
                        break;
                    case 179 :
                        min = 180;
                        break;
                    case 180 :
                        min = 181;
                        break;
                    case 181 :
                        min = 182;
                        break;
                    case 182 :
                        min = 183;
                        break;
                    case 183 :
                        min = 184;
                        break;
                    case 184 :
                        min = 185;
                        break;
                    case 185 :
                        min = 186;
                        break;
                    case 186 :
                        min = 187;
                        break;
                    case 187 :
                        min = 188;
                        break;
                    case 188 :
                        min = 189;
                        break;
                    case 189 :
                        min = 190;
                        break;
                    case 190 :
                        min = 191;
                        break;
                    case 191 :
                        min = 192;
                        break;
                    case 192 :
                        min = 193;
                        break;
                    case 193 :
                        min = 194;
                        break;
                    case 194 :
                        min = 195;
                        break;
                    case 195 :
                        min = 196;
                        break;
                    case 196 :
                        min = 197;
                        break;
                    case 197 :
                        min = 198;
                        break;
                    case 198 :
                        min = 199;
                        break;
                    case 199 :
                        min = 200;
                        break;
                    case 200 :
                        min = 201;
                        break;
                    case 201 :
                        min = 202;
                        break;
                    case 202 :
                        min = 203;
                        break;
                    case 203 :
                        min = 204;
                        break;
                    case 204 :
                        min = 205;
                        break;
                    case 205:
                        min = 206;
                        break;
                    case 206 :
                        min = 207;
                        break;
                    case 207 :
                        min = 208;
                        break;
                    case 208 :
                        min = 209;
                        break;
                    case 209 :
                        min = 210;
                        break;

                    case 210 :
                        mustCont = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }else{
                    mustCont = false;
                    min = 140;
                }
            }
            if(cur != null && cur.getCount()>0){
                cur.moveToFirst();

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialog.setTitle("Schedule Option 1 was chosen !")
                .setMessage("Based on the flight time chosen, the latest SkyBus available to take from"+ " " +cur.getString(0)+ "  " 
                                + "is"+ " " +cur.getString(2)+ " " + "which arrives at" + " " 
                        +cur.getString(1)+ " " + "at" + " " +cur.getString(3)+ ".")

                .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int but) {
                                dialog.cancel();    
                            }       
                        });

                dialog.show();
                dialog.create();

                }else {
                min = 140;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Flight Schedule not found !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }
```

Any suggestions? I hope you guys can help me out. It would be useful if you guys could paste the code to show how to implement this as i am not relli familiar with this. =/

Answer (score 0):

Make an async task of your ScheduleOp1 and keeping publishing update into a ProgressDialog on the main thread.
Follow the links:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog